# Spring MVC controller testing fails - content type not set

Tags: java, spring-mvc, testing, gradle

When I moved my application form Maven (Eclipse) to Gradle (InteliJ) All my Controller tests stopped working. Tests were working on old application with Maven.

My Controller method:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "submit", method = RequestMethod.POST, consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE, produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
public @ResponseBody FormResponse submitForm(@RequestBody TagData form) {
    try {
        tagService.saveTag(form);
    } catch (BusinessException ex) {
        return FormResponse.error(ex);
    }
    return FormResponse.success("admin.tag.saved");
}
```

My test:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(locations = {"/pl/dk/web/controllers/controllers-test-context.xml"})
@WebAppConfiguration
public class TagControllerTest {

    @Autowired
    TagController controller;

    @Autowired
    WebApplicationContext webContext;

    @Autowired
    TagManagerService tagService;

    private MockMvc mockMvc;

    @Before
    public void setUp() {
        mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders.webAppContextSetup(webContext).build();
        EasyMock.reset(tagService);
    }

      @Test
public void testSave() throws Exception {
    TagData form = new TagData();
    form.setName("Test tag");
    form.setDescription("Test description");

    EasyMock.expect(tagService.saveTag(form)).andReturn(1L);
    controller.tagService = tagService;

    RequestBuilder reqBuilder = MockMvcRequestBuilders.post("/admin/recipes/tag/submit")
            .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
            .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
            .content(TestUtil.convertObjectToString(form));

    MvcResult result = mockMvc.perform(reqBuilder)
            .andExpect(MockMvcResultMatchers.content().contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON))
            .andExpect(MockMvcResultMatchers.status().isOk())
            .andReturn();
    Assert.assertNotNull(result);
}
}
```

In my worst scenario, this problem may be connected with InteliJ integration with gradle or something, and I am fighting ghosts here. Can anyone help me with this?

My error:

```
java.lang.AssertionError: Content type not set
```

Comment: In my configuration files I got xml configurations with web context and mocked all services.

Answer (score 0):

I have found solution, altough it was not so obvious for me. Problem was connected with Jackson libraries. When I applied

```
testCompile 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:2.3.1'
```

instead of

```
testCompile 'org.codehaus.jackson:jackson-mapper-asl:1.9.13'
testCompile 'org.codehaus.jackson:jackson-core-asl:1.9.13'
```

all started to work.